# Truffle migration error Network up to date

Tags: truffle, sepolia

```
module.exports = {

  networks: {
    sepolia: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider({
        mnemonic: {
          phrase: MNEMONIC
        },
        privateKeys: private_keys,
        numberOfAddresses: 1,
        providerOrUrl: "https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/89930cbfab3e40c4a76f8a1ab466aa8c",
      }),
      network_id: 11155111, // Sepolia's network ID
      gas: 4000000, // Adjust the gas limit as per your requirements
    }
  },
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "^0.8.21",
    }
  },

};
```

this is my truffle-config file it says Network up to date.I run truffle migrate --reset it gives an error says
Something went wrong while attempting to connect to the network at http://127.0.0.1:7545. Check your network configuration.
CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node http://127.0.0.1:7545.
Truffle v5.11.5 (core: 5.11.5)
Node v20.9.0
How can i fix this

Comment: It seems it is reading the wrong configuration file. Can you check if you are executing the command in the right folder?